# How to catch postman.setNextRequest errors

Tags: javascript, postman

THE PROBLEM

In my current postman workflow, I heavily rely on the use of `postman.setNextRequest()`. This function accepts a string as parameter containing the name of the request to call next. When the string value contains a typo, the request will not get triggered.

QUESTION

Is there a way to catch any errors whenever the request I try to trigger doesn't exist? A.t.m. no error messages are being returned to the postman console what so ever and it's kind of hard to debug a test script whenever this happens.

Comment: Not helpful but this ```console.log(`This is the next Request Name: ${postman['__execution']['return']['nextRequest']}`)``` would show the `nextRequest` name when places after `setNextRequest()`.

Comment: Hi @DannyDainton it might be a bit helpful for some, so thank you for mentioning. In my case I use a data file that contains a array with request names to execute, so I can look at the list to see where the script stopped calling endpoints. But currently, nothing is telling me the request was not found. I might do a feature request for this if what I want is impossible.

Comment: Yeah just add a new FR on Github explaining your use case and what you're currently seeing/not seeing.

Comment: It's a really good feature to suggest non existing requests , setnextrequest should throw error or exception if request name is neither null nor existing requests

Comment: Please find my feature request [here](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/9822#issue-855240406).
Any thumbs up would be much appreciated :-)